# Wordpress widget with paginator (ajax , jquery)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I would like to have functionality on my site where I could display short messages.
These messages should be located within some box (div) and user should be able to  browse all messages using previous/next buttons. The message should be updated without page reload (ajax). In wp-admin I would like to have full CRUD management utils to handle these messages.

Are there any wordpress plugins/widgets or sth ready out of the box that can help me out
or maybe I need to write plugin/widget on my own ?

Tx in advanced

Comment: Michalski - This question is probably better suited for [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the jpaginate plugin.:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/17/jpaginate-a-fancy-jquery-pagination-plugin/

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

do you mean sth like this, marcin?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-pagination/